# Objective C - NSMutableArray issue after sorting using sortedArrayUsingDescriptors

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray with custom objects.

I can addObjects, removeAllObjects and other operations with the array.

However, as soon as I sort the array via sortedArrayUsingDescriptors i cannot 
perform any operations anymore such as removeallobjects. When debugging the code simply stops at this point.

Does anyone have an explanation ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: what bs answer is that?

Comment: It's not a BS answer, it's a closing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` returns a NSArray, not NSMutableArray.

you should use `sortUsingDescriptors:` to sort in place.

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:...];
```

vs.

```
[mutableArray sortUsingDescriptors:...];
```

Comment: ahhh this makes total sense. Awesome answer.

Comment: I will but I have to wait a few more minutes it tells me.

Comment: I will @Zero. Thanks to everyone helping me out here.